# How to configure PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and I want to configure `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, I try the following code, but doesn't not work:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // .......

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 50));
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SYS_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Page<Account>> query(@QuerydslPredicate Predicate predicate,
        @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(accountRepo.findAll(predicate, pageable), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And it is a simple Boot App, just playing with spring boot, with No Empty WebConfig Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public Filter html5ModeFilter() {
        return new Html5ModeFilter();
    }
}
```

And here's a list of my config classes:

```
Html5ModeFilter.java
SecurityConfig.java
ServletInitializer.java
UserDetailsAdapter.java
WebConfig.java
```

Comment: It seems correct. What do you mean by did not work?

Comment: The code is actually called, but has no affect, in other terms the when the fallback page request is not being used.

Comment: Add a controller that used a `Pageable` and more info about your project structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `@PageableDefault` from the:

```
public ResponseEntity<Page<Account>> query(..., @PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}
```

`PageableDefault` annotation looks like this:

```
public @interface PageableDefault {
    int value() default 10;
    int size() default 10;
    int page() default 0;
    ...
}
```

These `default` values are overriding your fallback value and you will see the first ten results.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `spring-data-commons` version `2.0`, there is are 2 new classes that will make this kind of thing easier:

- `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`
- `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer`

Unfortunately that's not the version that ships with the current version of Spring Boot (1.5.9), so replace at your own risk.

```
@Bean 
PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer sortCustomizer() {
    // s is PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver
    return p -> p.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 50));
}
```

This is just an alternative way to now set your fallback. @Ali Dehghani's answer still applies that the `Default` was overriding the `Fallback`

[Spring Data Web Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web)

Comment: This will completly override pageableCustomizer bean from SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.

Comment: Also be aware of this aspect: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverSupport.html#setFallbackPageable-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-